# Can Java be installed as non-root user with Chef?

Tags: java, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Chef supports execution as non-root user:
https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#run-as-non-root-user

But if the Chef recipe requires action with root access, then it will not work.

Does one of the Chef recipe to install Java support non-root installation? I didn't find reply in their documentation.

Comment: can you show us your steps ?

Answer (score 1):

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java, with java_home attribute value set to user accessible directory then it should be good.

Comment: But default recipe tries to use root as owner, even if java_home is customized.

Answer (score 1):

In general most community cookbooks expect to run as root, so you'll likely have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to install java as non-root user by using following code in recipes / default.rb:

```
arch = node['java']['arch']
jdk_version = node['java']['jdk_version']
tarball_url = node['java']['jdk'][jdk_version][arch]['url']
tarball_checksum = node['java']['jdk'][jdk_version][arch]['checksum']
bin_cmds = []
java_home = node['java']['java_home']

java_ark 'jdk' do
  url tarball_url
  checksum tarball_checksum
  bin_cmds bin_cmds
  app_home java_home
  owner node['current_user']
  action :install
end
```

And in attributes / default.rb file:

```
set['java']['jdk_version'] = '7'
set['java']['java_home'] = "/home/jpmat/jdk#{node['java']['jdk_version']}"
set['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms'] = 'true'
```